# OpenCV 3.0 VideoCapture doesn't open video file in Java

Tags: opencv3.0

OpenCV 3.0 with Java cannot open video file, but it woks with camera. Before I was using OpenCV 3.0-beta it was working well in both, but in OpenCV 3.0 which is released on 2015-04-24 doesn't work with video file.

If anyone know about this problem of OpenCV 3, please tell me the reason and how to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem like this: Copy the `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin` to the system path and restart the Eclipse.

Hope this help someone that may has this problem with OpenCV 3.0.

Comment: Thanks!  I was just getting an unhelpful "Couldn't open video file." message which made it seem like it wasn't finding video file.  I added the path, and it worked.  I guess it just wasn't finding the ffmpeg libs.  Is there another error log somewhere that gives more info about problems like this?

Comment: You are welcome. No there is no more information about this error, usually OpenCV doesn't give more information when throwing some exception. And also I have a problem whit new version of OpenCV (3.0) which I cannot write Video, because there is no VideoWriter class in OpenCV Java bindings. Could you tell the solution how to write frames. Thanks

Comment: No, I have not tried writing frames, only reading frames from mp4 which works fine for me in Opencv 3.0.  Sounds like that issue is probably worthy of a different stackoverflow question thread.

Answer (score 1):

Even after adding `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin` to SYSTEM path, if you cannot open VideoCapture then you could also try coping `opencv_ffmpegXXX_64.dll` from `opencv/build/java/x64` or from `opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin`. I don't know why this works but it worked for me after trying:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29920295/677185 and https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4974

Answer (score 1):

Generally opencv_ffmpegXXX.dll file not placed at opencvjavaXXX.dll file folder so you need to  load two library in java code

You should have try this.

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); // for OpencvjavaXXX.dll 

System.loadLibrary("opencv_ffmpeg320_64"); // for OpenCV_ffmpegXXX.dll file
```

You can specify full DLL file path into the (string) parameter