# Opencv open a video files but capture isOpened always falses

Tags: java, opencv, video-capture

I tried to use opencv java interface to capture the video, I find isOpened is always false.

I have tried different video format and different version (2.4.11 and 3.0.0), both met the same issues.

I have configure "-Djava.library.path=D:\Project\opencv\opencv3.0\build\x64\vc12\bin", and have copied opencv_java300.dll to this folder.

And I checked tips [OpenCV 3.0 VideoCapture doesn't open video file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899471/opencv-3-0-videocapture-doesnt-open-video-file-in-java) and [OpenCV 2.4 VideoCapture not working on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows), neither works for me.

Anyone knows what's the trick part to capture the video?

The sample code I have is:

```
    VideoCapture capture=new VideoCapture();
    capture.open("D:\\StopMoti2001.mpeg");
    if(!capture.isOpened()){
        return;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried passing the file to VideoCaputre's constructor?

`VideoCapture capture=new VideoCapture("D:\\StopMoti2001.mpeg");`

I did it with an input from webcam and was like this:
`VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);`  where 0 indicates the 1st camera. 

Maybe is similar for an input from file.

Comment: Yes, there is no difference, I also tried mp4, avi, all get the same issues. There is no log been printed, but capture does not opened.

Comment: can you try to open an jpeg file with videocapture? if that works there might be a codec problem?

Comment: can you upload a small video file you tried?

Comment: can you try to copy the opencv_ffmpeg dll file to your folder? it doesn't give an error if missing but is needed to access codec

Comment: I put the dll in windows/system32 folder, I can parse the video now, thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you solved this issue Vincent.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue but thanks tou your comments I have figured it out. For anyone intrested in the solution:
copy opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll from opencv/build/java/x64 folder to your project main folder (containing folders: src, .settings, bin).